# Application name in Google Glass Menu

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

In Google Glass the menu shows the launch keyword of an app. But for example, viewfinder shows as:

```
"Show viewfinder"
```

And in the launch keywords list as:

```
"Show the viewfinder".
```

It is possible show in the menu the application name, and in the voice list the launch keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about with your sample "Show viewfinder" is a [Listed Voice Command](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/app/VoiceTriggers.Command)

If you use in your trigger xml the following code, you will have in your menu "Show Demo", and by voice "Show me a demo" :

```
<trigger command="SHOW_ME_A_DEMO" />
```

It is not possible to have a different sentence by voice and menu if you do not take a listed voice command. If you want to use custom trigger word, use this method : [Unlisted Voice Command](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice#unlisted_commands)

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [the Voice Command Checklist](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/voice-checklist)?

The first one:

> (The command) is general enough to apply to multiple Glassware, but still has a clear purpose.

I think if you use the App name, it will break the guideline.

But feel free to try at https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/voice-form.

And BTW, if you are not looking for publishing on MyGlass, you can technically use any command you want :)